# How do i set up mysql server and database where everyone can access with the right credential?

Tags: mysql

I just started using mysql in my work place as an intern. I have a few question regarding MYSQL server and workbench. I have been searching online for a simple explanation but i can't seem to understand.

I have already installed MySQL server and workbench and have have set up local instance MySQL router. So now i'm trying to set up a database server where can i access through excel which i have no idea on how to.

So can anyone please provide a short explanation without the technical details for each question below?
1) how do i set up a database server where everyone can access the data from different desktop?
2) Or do i need data warehouse like Redshift to store my data?
3) can it be done without paying a single cent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a database server (such as [AWS RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/)). There you can store your data. For [connecting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html) to a database anyone would need `host` (connection url), `username`, `password`, `port` (default: 3306). You can also provide different [access levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html) for your database if you want to restrict users to have only desired privileges.